# How the JVM executes JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, jnienv

I've been using JNI a bit recently, and I wonder something...
How JNI gets executed?

For example, `DefineClass` is in the `JNINativeInterface_`, but, it has no code in [jni.h](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/native/include/jni.h).
This might be a C++ specific thing, but I don't know a lot about C++/Memory/etc.

Comment: You'll have to look in the source code for the specific JVM that you're targeting, if it's available. For example, [here is](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/refs/heads/master/runtime/jni/jni_internal.cc#496) the `FindClass` implementation in Android's ART (I didn't use `DefineClass` because ART doesn't support it).

Comment: Oh got it. I looked into the cpp file which implements the functions : [openjdk](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/161333eeba1d4ac163991d6697c24f3a59148b2b/src/hotspot/share/prims/jni.cpp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the source code of openjdk : [click](http://Oh%20got%20it.%20I%20looked%20into%20the%20cpp%20file%20which%20implements%20the%20functions%20[link](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/161333eeba1d4ac163991d6697c24f3a59148b2b/src/hotspot/share/prims/jni.cpp))